# Formula to display number format and text together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My cell A2 value is 1512215.22USD (text format, no commas or points), I need a formula to convert (can also be in text format) in B2 as 1,512,215.22 USD. The value may vary between .01 to 100,000,000.00 maximum.

I also wonder possible to execute an excel event when A2 is selected to apply in A2 while entering the value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it always USD?

Comment: replace all "USD" with "" to convert them to numbers, and change the Custom Number Format to `#,###.00 "USD"`

Comment: Can be in USD, GBP or EUR with 3 letters

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this will only be USD ...
[image]

Comment: To answer your second question ... yes it is possible to execute an excel event when A2 is selected to apply in A2 ..... but if you use the above formula and cell formatting .... it doesn't really make sense to create an event.

Comment: Nice solution that returns a true number rather than text *(+1)*

Comment: The currency can be changed between USD, GBP & EUR but always with 3 letters. For excel event I mean if I use If intersect... code with this formula can it works automatically when I enter a value to A2?

Comment: This site isn't a source for free code ... you will need to show us what you tried and then we can help you fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

This function ought to do it - just use it in the event but make sure you disable events before you write the response to the cell and enable them again after  or it will loop.

```
Function formatmoney(unformatted As String) As String
    Dim numberpart, currencypart As String

    numberpart = Left(unformatted, Len(unformatted) - 3)
    currencypart = Right(unformatted, 3)
    formatmoney = Format(Val(numberpart), "#,##0.00") & " " & currencypart
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I copied your function to a module and before to use in an event procedure I create a procedure as "Sub Callformatmoney()" in the same module with this code "ActiveSheet.Range("A3") = formatmoney" but always has an error of "Compile Eror: Arguament not Options"

Comment: If you are converting the contents of A3 then you'd want `ActiveSheet.Range("A3") = formatmoney(range("A3"))`